# How to change https://www.google.co.uk/maps/search/@53.0725236,0.0423795,11.44z to be user location rather than mine?

Tags: android, html, android-studio, web

I want to put a link to a simple google search in my app. So if I search myself this is the link...

https://www.google.co.uk/maps/search/dog+groomer+near+me/@53.0725236,0.0423795,11.44z

It obviously has my coordinates in it. Is there a way for me to change it to a generic link so it automatically uses the users location?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use Android's location manager.  This will allow you to get the user's coordinates (as long as they have location enabled on their phone.)

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/#location

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies

It is up to you what you do with this.  You can do a quick string replace and insert the user's coordinates inside the url.  Or you could even include the google maps component into your app and have the results show up right in your app.

Comment: Any idea what I would replace the link with?

Comment: It depends on your application, but if you all you want is to use the user's location, use the links I posted to capture the users location object.  That will contain the user's coordinates.  Then just replace your coordinates in the url: "https://www.google.co.uk/maps/search/dog+groomer+near+me/@"+usersLat + "," + usersLong

Comment: You can get the user's latitude and longitude by using the Location Services provided by Android.  There are some code samples in these links and you can find some basic guides online.